# How to get user's sessions when using the database session driver?

Tags: laravel

I  want to check the logged-in user and the user_id column in Session table and also count the result. So I tried to use this

```
    $login = Session::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();
```

But it returned this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::where()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use `DB` facade:

   ```php
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

   $login = DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();
   ```
2. define a new `Session` model and use it to count logins:

   - `php artisan make:model Session`

     ```php
     $login = \App\Session::where('user_id', Auth::id())->count();
     ```
   - By this way, you can also define a `sessions` relationship
     on user model:

     ```php
     class User extends Authenticatable
     {
         /**
          * Get the sessions of the user.
          */
         public function sessions()
         {
             return $this->hasMany('App\Session');
         }
     }
     ```

     and call it like this:

     ```php
     $login = Auth::user()->sessions()->count();
     ```